# find row with multiple attributes

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of size `10000x5` with format `[id, year, month, day, value]`

For example:

```
[ 1 2004 1 1 100;
  1 2004 1 2 201;
  2 2004 1 1  30;
  2 2004 1 2 123;
  2 2005 1 1 300;
  2 2005 1 2 103;
  ...]
```

I would like to filter and copy a subset of this matrix into another matrix, given the search criteria `year==2004 && month==1 && day==1`. So what I thought is to first find out what is the row index of vectors which match to the given criteria.

First I tried with,

```
[row] = find((data(:,2) == 2004 && data(:,3) == 1 && data(:,4) == 1));
```

But it doesn't seems to work with multiple criteria, I get the error

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
```

Next I tried with

```
key = [2004 1 1];
[~,index] = ismember(data,key,'rows')
```

But it said

```
Error using ismember. A and S must have the same number of columns.
```

Is there any way to refine the syntax, or another API to search with multiple criteria?

Comment: Oh, it works with  [row] = find((data(:,2) == 2004 & data(:,3) == 1 & data(:,4) == 1));

Comment: You can answer your own question if you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the proposed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293118/find-corresponding-rows-if-it-has-some-missing-elements). It proposes an alternative approach. In your case, you would have :

```
key = [NaN 2004 1 1 NaN];
```